# I got a problem with Nginx and docker conf on flask gunicorn app

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn, nginx-config

I work on a computer. I have two servers, my personal server (server 1) and a work server (server 2).

In my home, my flask website run on server 1 without problem. I configure Nginx to link with my domain name (http://exemple.adrien.com).

The problem is on server 2.

I install my app on server 2 with docker compose. When i curl the docker-machine ip with my app port (192.168.99.100:5000) I have a successful response.

However, I can't run my website on other local machines. When I access http://x.x.x.x:8080/ on my computer web browser, I get the Nginx webpage.

But when I access http://10.x.x.197:5000/ I have no response.

I have tried many Nginx conf files and I have the same result.

My `server_name` isn't a string, it's just my server 2 IP address.

I have tried many configurations in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available` for the same result.

On my server 1, I have no problem to configure Nginx with a `server_name` like test.test.eu, but on server 2 I have absolutely no idea how to configure with an IP like 1.1.1.1:5000.

My docker-compose runs the flask app on port 5000.

Comment: Tanks for correct my text!

Comment: Hello,

I solved it.
The problem was cause of mac os.
Server 1 is on debian, and server 2 on a mac mini (mac os x).
Os x use "docker for mac", and this tools was blocking me